# Как сделать чтобы все находящиеся комы менялись на точки?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я из ListView вытягиваю значения  между двумя знаками $ .
Проблема в чем ниже представлен код и он хорошо работает если между числами стоит точка . Но если вдруг будет стоять кома то программа летит.(потому что складываются числа)

Как сделать чтобы все находящиеся комы менялись на точки

```
private String s = "text from item";

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        // берём строку из списка по нажатой позиции
                        String row = titleList.get(i);
                        // находим первый $
                        int start = row.indexOf("$");
                        if (start == -1) { // если не нашли
                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }   
                        // находим второй $
                        int end = row.indexOf("$", start + 1);
                        if (end == -1) { // если не нашли
                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        // вырезаем кусок из строки по найденным позициям
                        // и присваиваем переменной
                        s = row.substring(start + 1, end);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: `s.replaceAll(",", ".");` ? Eсли нужно заменить все не точки и не цифры - `s.replaceAll("[^.\\d]", ".");`-

Comment: (Нужно заменить только комы цифры не трогать   )прям две строчки писать  в любое место?

Comment: Если только комы, то только первая строка. Вставляйте после `s = row.substring(start + 1, end);`. Причем так `s = s.replaceAll(",", ".");`

Comment: Спасибо работает.Но когда Получается число  к примеру 10.344.45 то вылетает нужно  из того числа взять 10.344 то есть захватить первую точку и все знаки до второй

Comment: Запятые здесь являются разделителем разрядов (тысячи, миллионы и т.д.), а не целой и дробной части. Может у вас какая-то другая задача, но чтобы получить правильное число, нужно их либо убрать, либо парсить с указанием правильной локали.

Comment: как их убрать  что бы захватывалась первая точка и все цифры до 2 точки

Comment: Вы мой коммент внимательно прочли? `"1,000,000.01"` - это миллион и одна копейка. Какое число вы хотите из этой строки получить, единицу или миллион?

Comment: Чем больше тем лучше  главное чтобы была всего  одна точка               ( потому как если будет две точки 100.565.4) будет сбой . или кома  тоже будет сбой

Comment: "Чем больше тем лучше" +1000