# Как отбросить все после второй точки?

Tags: java, android

Я из ListView вытягиваю значения между двумя знаками $ . Проблема в чем ниже представлен код и он хорошо работает . Но если вдруг будет стоять две точки вот пример 10.978.86 то программа летит.(потому что складываются числа) 
Как отбросить все после второй точки включая точку чтобы было 10.978

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private String s = "text from item";

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                            // берём строку из списка по нажатой позиции
                            String row = titleList.get(i);
                            // находим первый $
                            int start = row.indexOf("$");
                            if (start == -1) { // если не нашли
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // находим второй $
                            int end = row.indexOf("$", start + 1);
                            if (end == -1) { // если не нашли
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // вырезаем кусок из строки по найденным позициям
                            // и присваиваем переменной
                            s = row.substring(start + 1, end);
                            s = s.replaceAll(",", ".");

                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, (s), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
```

/////

```
// находим первый .
                        int start1 = s.indexOf(".");
                        if (start1 == -1) { // если не нашли
                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        // находим второй .
                        int end1 = s.indexOf(".", start1 + 1);
                        if (end1 == -1) { // если не нашли
                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        // вырезаем кусок из строки по найденным позициям
                        // и присваиваем переменной
                        s = s.substring(0, end1);
                        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
                });
```

Comment: Если находишь два символа $, то несложно догадаться, как по аналогии найти две точки.

Comment: А с учетом предыдущего вопроса нужно сначала находить точку, а потом уже заменять запятые на точки.

Comment: Прикол в чем я могу найти  по аналогии  только первую точку. а мне нужно обрезать вплоть до второй

Comment: Вот поэтому надо сначала отбросить все после точки, а потом заменять запятые.

Comment: Просто понимаете  бывают числа  (0.3261) а  бывают (10,590.44 ) может первая попасться  кома  а может и точка. Я же делаю универсально все перевожу до значений с точками. А потом хочу обрезать чтобы была одна точка и числа до второй 10.590

Comment: Не вижу в этом никакой проблемы.

Comment: Я НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК ЭТО НАПИСАТЬ (я за вас рад)

Comment: Прикол в том, что код точно такой-же, только `$` заменить на точку и `substring(0, end)` взять с нулевой позиции. Только всё это уже на переменной `s`. Больше добавить нечего - должны же вы хоть чему-то научиться, а не только готовое копипастить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать чтобы все находящиеся комы менялись на точки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014344/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Не получается  (Прикол в том, что код точно такой-же, только $ заменить на точку и substring(0, end) взять с нулевой позиции. Только всё это уже на переменной s. Больше добавить нечего - должны же вы хоть чему-то научиться, а не только готовое копипастить.)  я код добавил в описание что не так ошибка Not have data.

Comment: А если подумать? В добавленном коде тосты лишние - ибо ненахождение точки не является ошибкой, а только поводом не выполнять последующий код. То есть незачем дробить строку, когда в ней нет первой или второй точки. Но вся соль в том, что вы так и не поняли мой посыл в предыдущем вопросе: точка и запятая в числах - это совсем не одно и тоже. Отбрасывая "лишнее" вы на самом деле выбрасываете тысячи и миллионы долларов, из-за чего пользователей вашего приложения кондратий схватит. Потому что они увидят, что валюта в 1000 раз дешевле чем они купили её вчера )))

Answer (score 0):

```
   public  String cutSecondDot(String str){
    int firstDot= str.indexOf(".");
    if(firstDot==-1) return str;
    int secondDot=str.indexOf(".",firstDot+1);
    if(secondDot==-1) return str;
    return str.substring(0,secondDot);
}
```